# VBA: How to search for * using Find?

Tags: vba, excel, escaping, wildcard

I am trying to search for the string ** in a column in a worksheet, but I have trouble making this work as * also works as a wildcard when using find. To complicate it further the same column also includes *, so I need to find ** specifically. I have tried the below code so far, and in both cases it appears to find the first non-empty cell, which happens to be *.

```
Set searchRange = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Find(Chr(42) & Chr(42), LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Alternatively:

```
Set searchRange = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Find("**", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

I have used Chr() succesfully to escape " many times before, but it does not seem to work here. I have googled for solutions, but this solution is the only answer I have found so far, which does not work.

An alternative solution might be to loop through the range and do a string comparison. This feels like a rather ugly solution though.

EDIT: Was easier than I thought. Apparently this works:

```
Set searchRange = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Find("~*~*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: Sounds odd, but try finding `"~*~*"`

Comment: Just found the same solution by googling some more, and came back to update my answer. It works.

Comment: @BruceWayne: Why this sounds odd? It's documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214138

Comment: @AxelRichter - I didn't realize it was documented. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard (*) can be escaped using tilde (~), this can thus be solved like this:

```
Set searchRange = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Range("B:B").Find("~*~*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

[Official source, posted by Axel Richter in comments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214138/)